# how to get the accessible folder names from a drive with vb.net (Visual Studio 2012 Express)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create a program for a friend that allows him to "sort out" and locate his files.
He has a couple of drives and many folders.  What I would like to do for him is:

1. Have code that lists all of the active drives in a combo box. He can then select which drive he wants to search for any or just selected file types by extension.
2. Then he either selects "Everything" or a specific type (ie: Music)
3. Once a button is clicked, a list box fills with the full path to the file

Beginning this writing process, I have accomplished this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Button1.Enabled = False

    Dim allDrives() As DriveInfo = DriveInfo.GetDrives()

    Dim d As DriveInfo
    For Each d In allDrives
        If d.IsReady Then ComboBox1.Items.Add(d)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then

        Try

            For Each DName As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(ComboBox1.Text, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly)
                Dim LDN As Integer = Len(DName)
                Dim FName As String = Strings.Mid(DName, 4, LDN - 3)
                CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(FName, False)
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

My first problem is that the GetDirectories process is getting directories I know that I do not have access to.  I am trying to figure out how to prevent this.  Can anyone help me.

Comment: You need to catch the `UnauthorizedAccessException` in the loop to skip them. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58620178/14171304 for example.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry.  i did not fully read all of his comments before I just tried catching an UnauthorizedAccessException, which obviously didn't work.  I understand why this don't work but don't know how to code this so it does.  Can I get some help?

Comment: @Smokey Exactly which exception *is* thrown?

Comment: Andrew, I don't get any exceptions, that is my problem.  I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed but I sorta understand some of what was explained.  I think that I read that GetDirectories don't work in the type of loop I am using.  That's ok.  So I need to create a function that will return an authorized directory each time it is called THEN put the values in the CheckedListBox I am using.  If I am wrong, please explain why.  If I am right, how do you do this?

Comment: Can anyone help me?  In the above example, my code gets ALL of the directories perfectly and drops them into a checked list box.  If the user (me) selects one of the directories that is "off limits" and I attempt to query that directory for any files, I get the exception error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18' is denied.

Comment: If you want to page someone, prepend `@` to the name like @AndrewMorton  :) Otherwise no body is hearing you. I just came here by accident. As for your problem, I gave you an example to resolve it. What is not working for you? The referred example will skip directories like `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18` so you should not have any in the list. Also, do you need to get only the top-level files or all the files from all the sub folders? Please elaborate.